# Can't find VWDExpress.exe in IDE folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just downloaded and installed VS 2015 for windows desktop. But I don't have the ASP.NET developer IDE (VWDExpress.exe)

Comment: Any particular reason to use VS14? VS15 is already available and VS14 will no longer receive updates.

Comment: it doesn't matter. I think I just missed a setting or something. any ideas?

Comment: You probably forgot to install the ASP.NET workload. If you were using VS15, then it's available [here](http://i.imgur.com/JvcoUEs.png). That said, it's generally a bad idea to use outdated and unsupported software.